# Problema con selección errónea en DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un DataGridView con datos de RUT(n°Cedula), nombre y apellidos de personas; en el cual selecciono una fila y el DataGridView me selecciona otra persona erróneamente. Me refleja correctamente lo seleccionado en el DataGridView en los ComboBox y en los TextBox. Lo erróneo esta en la selección del DataGridView.

```
void dataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){

    txt_nombre.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    txt_apellidos.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

    cmb_comuna.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    Cmb_titulos.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
    Cmb_instituciones.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
    cmb_Cursos.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
    txt_experiencia.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
    cmb_Contrato.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[12].Value.ToString();
    Cmb_cargos.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[13].Value.ToString();
    Cmb_areas.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[17].Value.ToString();          
}
```

Comment: No termino de entender a que te refieres con que "te selecciona a otra persona". Si tu haces click en una fila, te selecciona otra fila diferente?

Comment: Tampoco logro entender tu problemática, te puedo sugerir que cambies el evento **_MouseDoubleClick** por **_CellDoubleClick** y llenar los campos de la siguiente manera. ** txt_nombre.Text  = dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value**

Comment: ¿El problema es que recuperas correctamente la información de lo seleccionado, pero en el DataGridView aparece seleccionado otra fila (como si no pintara bien que se haya seleccionado otra fila)?

Comment: exactamente Pikoh,davlio,silvestre silva selecciono a cierta persona en el datagridview y me aparece otra como seleccionada en el mismo datagridview

Comment: En ese caso, no tiene nada que ver con el código que nos muestras. Probablemente en algún otro lado estes modificando la fila seleccionada. Deberías proporcionarnos un [mcve] para que podamos probar y ver cual es el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que al usar `SelectedRows[0]` solo consideras una fila selecciona, por ende podrías limpiar la selección que tiene tu `DataGridView` y seleccionar la fila en la que realizas el doble click.

Para ello harías uso de `HitTest` para obtener información de tu `DataGridView` con las coordanadas `X` e `Y`, el cual devuelve un objeto de tipo `HitTestInfo` que tiene la propiedad `RowIndex`. En caso sea negativo indicará que no esta seleccionando una fila.

```
void dataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){

    var indiceFila = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;

    if (indiceFila == -1) return;

    txt_nombre.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    txt_apellidos.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

    cmb_comuna.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    Cmb_titulos.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
    Cmb_instituciones.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
    cmb_Cursos.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
    txt_experiencia.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
    cmb_Contrato.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[12].Value.ToString();
    Cmb_cargos.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[13].Value.ToString();
    Cmb_areas.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[17].Value.ToString();

    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    dataGridView1.Rows[indiceFila].Selected = true;     
}
```

---

**Referencia:**

- [Método DataGridView.HitTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.hittest(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Clase DataGridView.HitTestInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.hittestinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

Utilizaría el DataGridView.HitTest.

```
DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
```

Y ahora puedes acceder a la fila:

```
var row = dataGridView1.Rows[hit.RowIndex];
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la diferencia de tu respuesta con la mía?

Comment: En tu respuesta sigues usando .SelectedRows[0].Cells... para rellenar los textos de cada control. Lo que sugiero es usar la variable 'row' para ello, row.Cells.... Únicamente usas el rowIndex del HitTestInfo para luego seleccionar la fila (que debe estar seleccionada porque se le ha hecho doble click).